# React-Router: Nesting routes without nesting components with wildcard paths

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am trying to create routes like the following:

`http://www.domain.com/@username` &

`http://www.domain.com/@username/album-slug`

For the first one, I set up my route as:

    `<Route path = "@*" view = "Full" component = {UserContainer} />`

For the second one, I set up my route as:

    `<Route path= "@*/:albumSlug" view = "Full" component = {AlbumContainer} />`

They work when alone but I can't get both of them to work together, wherein each Route only loads that container (not the parent one, i.e.: Album Container is loaded in the second route and not the User Container).

What I have tried and hasn't worked yet is nesting them or having them one after the other one, or using `IndexRoute` (all below)

```
/* Nesting - didn't work */
<Route path = "@*" view = "Full" component = {UserContainer} >
    <Route path= "@*/:albumSlug" view = "Full" component = {AlbumContainer} />
</Route>

/* Sequential - didn't work */
<Route path = "@*" view = "Full" component = {UserContainer} />
<Route path= "@*/:albumSlug" view = "Full" component = {AlbumContainer} />

/* IndexRoute - didn't work */
<Route path = "@**" >
    <IndexRoute view = "Full" component = {UserContainer}/>
    <Route path= "@*/:albumSlug" view = "Full" component = {AlbumContainer} />
</Route>
```

So, long story short, is there a way to have two routes which seem nested but don't require nested components when dealing with paths with wildcards? Ideally, this would work for multiple level of nesting - if I was to also support URLs like:

`http://www.domain.com/@username/album-slug/image-slug`
`http://www.domain.com/@username/comments`

I feel like I am missing something in the understanding of nested routes or `IndexRoute`. Any ideas or pointers here would be much appreciated!

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things to remember:

1. The order of the routes matters.
2. Use `:paramName` over `*` when appropriate for clarity

Try one of these:

```
// IndexRoute
<Route path="@:username">
  <IndexRoute view="Full" component={UserContainer} />
  <Route path=":albumSlug" view="Full" component={AlbumContainer} />
</Route>

// Sequential
<Route path="@:username/:albumSlug" view="Full" component={AlbumContainer} />
<Route path="@:username" view="Full" component={UserContainer} />
```

Comment: Thank you! That worked - not sure why I chose to use `*` over `:paramName`. For those who stumble upon this issue in the future, another thing which worked was the reverse sequence mentioned in the sequential solution above.